# Android Studio 3.6.1, Could not create an instance of type org.gradle.internal.locking.DefaultDependencyLockingProvider

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I'm facing problem with the latest version of Android Studio which is 3.6.1. I have a project which was develop using Android Studio 2.1.2 and now I decide to switch to use the latest version. After I update my project file to latest version follow the instruction of the Android Studio, I cannot sync my gradle. Here is the error I'm facing

[image]

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

Try 'import' rather than 'open' old projects when using any latest version of Android Studio. If it still fails, perhaps create a new project and port the existing codes over. The versions are too far apart from 2.1.2 to now 3.6.1.

Comment: Hi lurker, thanks for your reply, I have tried 'import' still come out the same error. So I create a new project and port the existing code over as you suggested. Now come out another problem, when I try to build my project, it show 'Gradle build failed with 1 error(s) in 77 ms' without mention what exactly the error is. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Nope. Tip is to port in slowly, step-by-step, and compile regularly to ensure no errors before porting in more codes.

Comment: Now I worry maybe is my Android Studio setting not proper, I try create a new project with just add in some text and buttons, it also show me the same error that build fail.

Answer (score 0):

Change the jdk Version to 9.0.4
This worked for me.